# next/link inside a div which has a onClick function, how to ignore it from Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js `Link` element inside a `div` which has a `onClick` function which `router.push` to a URL. How to make the `Link` element ignore the `onClick` function and push to the URL from `Link` `href`?

```
<div onClick={() => router.push(`/${post.tag}/status/${id}`)}>
    <Link href={`/{username}`}>
        <span className='text-blue-500 hover:underline'>{username}</span>
    </Link>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you should use stopPropagation .

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the Link element ignore the `onClick` function and push to the URL from `Link` href, we need to add an `event.stopPropagation()` inside the `onClick` function of `Link`.

```
<Link 
    href={`/{username}`} 
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        router.push(`/${post.tag}/status/${id}`);
    }}
>
    <span className='text-blue-500 hover:underline'>{username}</span>
</Link>
```